# UrbanCode Deploy multiple environment approver

Tags: urbancode

In IBM Urbancode deploy, I configured an environment with approval process. When deploy application on environment, an email is generated to the approval team. One user can login to urbancode deploy and approve the deployment.

I want to configure the environment in such a way that atlease 3 member of approval team should approve the deployment, then only deployment should start. It should not deploy application only with one user approval. Please help.

Comment: Are you not connected to SC? Merges can be vote approved with at least one jenkims plugin, as well as probably many other ways, not least via terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only takes one approver to advance an approval. There's no way to set it so a certain number of people on the notification list must approve.

If you want multiple approvals, you can add multiple steps to the approval process. You could have a separate approval for the application and environment, or you could have multiple approval steps for the environment, and then inform everyone that each person can approve only one of the steps. You could also set up different approval teams and have 1 approval required from each team.

[Approval process with three environment approval steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8qt0.gif)